# Can this setup produce a no interference pattern from entangled photons from a BBO crystal?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics, quantum-eraser

[Related question from physics exchange where the pictures were taken:](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/274615/why-does-a-bbo-crystal-put-after-2-slits-make-the-interference-pattern-disappear)

[From the delayed choice eraser paper from Kim et al. 1999](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9903047v1.pdf)

[image: dual slit eraser]

My question is probably quite simple. I want to know if changing the transmittance and reflectance coefficients from the semi-transparent mirrors $BS_a$ and $BS_b$ will affect at all the expected pattern measured in $D_0$.

I mean, shouldn't $D_0$ be a sum of all of $R_1..R_4$? If so, wouldn't changing those parameters change $D_0$?

If it does change $D_0$, then isn't this a violation of the [no-communication theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem)?

(Why would this be a violation of the no-communication theorem? Well, say you use a mechanical shutter to change between those 2 types of mirrors: normal mirror fully reflective, and no mirror, fully transmitive. Simply by observing $D_0$ you would be able to infer the position of the mirrors (and get a clear "no interference pattern" in $D_0$), ergo, faster than light communication)

If it doesn't change anything, then where do those photons go (or more generally, what happens)?

[image: expected measurements from detectors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an ideal system (with no loss or scattering in any of the elements), $D_0$ will indeed see the number of photons equal to those detected in the other half of the system. But changing the beamsplitter coefficients doesn’t change the number of photons, it merely redistributes them among the various detectors. So the number of photons measured by $D_0$ will remain the same.

Of course, switching the beamsplitters will change the likelihood of a which-path measurement, and so the likelihood of a photon landing on the interference pattern will change, but this would only be evident through coincidence comparisons. So the no-communication theorem survives.

I should stress: In the delayed-choice quantum eraser experiment, there is *never* an interference pattern, except in coincidence comparisons.

Comment: What I was wondering is whether changing the way the detectors are configured would affect at all the pattern in $D_0$, so how the distributions occur seem to be important. I am not talking about projection deformations, but the relative intensities of each component, because if that would change on the eraser side, so it needs to change on the short path side. For physics to work, nothing I do on the long path should change anything visible (without the coincidence circuit) and this is what I am trying to ask. How, and why does it not?

Comment: I mean, I think I kind of see it. If the valleys and troughs from $R_1$  and $R_2$ perfectly line themselves up and the maximums of $R_1$ coincide with $R_4$ (and the same for $R_2$, $R_3$ ), no matter what ratio of diffractions/non-diffractions you have, it will still result in the same overall sum. But is this the case? Or can I have unmatched intensities from $R_1$ to $R_2$ ?

Comment: @user27221 I think I understand you. What you say reminds me of this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.5098  Take a look and see if that’s relevant and answers your question.

Comment: yup. this is pretty much it. thank you!